# Can I make write18 send command lines to Cygwin bash instead of Windows command interpreter?

Tags: miktex, windows, shell-escape, cygwin

I am using Windows 7, Cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-6.6-WOW64), and MiKTeX 2.9. I am trying to compile a document of a friend of mine who has written a specific document class file (.cls), a class that is able to run Python code from the document LaTeX source (.tex) and include its output in the document (maybe along with the Python code). I want (in a sense, I need) to write my own documents using that class.

My friend works on Linux, and I try to compile his document from a Cygwin terminal by using `pdflatex --enable-write18 thedocumentfile.tex` (indeed, my command line is `PATH=.:$PATH pdflatex --enable-write18 thedocumentfile.tex`). If I search for `latex` packages in my Cygwin Setup, I only find `texlive-collection` ones, not installed, so I guess `pdflatex` is calling a latex-to-PDF compiler version in a MiKTeX 2.9 package called `miktex-pdftex-base-2.9`. I think this is what I want, just one LaTeX distribution (MiKTeX) installed in my machine.

But compilation fails because command lines passed as arguments to `\write18` are written to be interpreted by a `bash`, but my compilation attempts send them to a Windows command interpreter.

I don't know if it is possible to instruct my compiler not to pass command lines to the Windows interpreter, but to the `bash` shell of Cygwin. I hope it will. Does anybody know how?

Comment: you can get the cygwin compiled texlive 2012 from tug rather than from cygwin and run on cygwin (that's what I use) that uses bash by default I couldn't see in texlive a customisation for the shell it uses, don't know about miktex.

Comment: Thank you very much, @David, I will try your suggestion in case no one knows how to force MiKTeX to do what I need. I would prefer not to change my LaTeX distribution (nor mix two of them) if avoidable.

Comment: If what you are really going for is using Python from LaTeX, you might consider [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).  It works well with Windows, and can be faster than some of the Python-LaTeX solutions based on `\write18` (it saves output, so only modified code is executed).

Comment: Using `c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "<bash commands>"` will run `<bash commands>` via Cygwin, but at least on my system it's really slow.

Comment: @G. Poore: Thanks for your comments. Regarding PythonTex, it is not the kind of solution I am looking for, because the class file I want to use provides more than just Python facilities. Regarding how to call Cygwin `bash` from the Windows interpreter, it is the ugly solution I have adopted, so thank you very much, this allows me to make compilation work (after modifying the `\write18` arguments in the class file). However, I'm still interested in configuring MiKTeX in order to make it use `bash` so I can use the original class file (or other `bash`-supported class files in the future).

Answer (score 2):

To sidestep the question with a moralistic injunction: it's fundamentally unportable to have complex shell scripts embedded in Tex documents.  Much better is to use `\write18` to call a program (with arguments, if needs be) as a system call, which will be interpreted the same by either bash or as a Windows command shell call.

You might be able to encourage your friend to refactor his class file into a few shell scripts plus the class file which invokes those scripts by plain system calls.

#### What is a system call

They are the "atoms" of shell scripts, that in Unix/C are invoked using the `system()` C function, which is included in most scripting languages such as Python.  It may have switches or arguments, but it won't have anything like control structures, pipelines, or IO redirection operators.